# Openshift process environment variable for HTTPS for node application

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, openshift

OpenShift has a `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` `process.env` variable which works well with HTTP.

However, I could not find any information about HTTPS. Is there another `process.env` variable for it? Or should I use `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` for HTTPS too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https is terminated at the node level proxy that is in front of your gear, so the ssl never actually reaches your gear directly.  You should just write your application as if it is using http and it will be fine.  if you need to determine whether or not it was accessed via https, look for the x-forwarded-for http header.

Comment: Thanks Corey. I spent a few hours try to work out how to use HTTPS in a Node.js application on Openshift before finding your answer here. It might be good if the Openshift documentation spelled this out more explicitly for the benefit of other Node.js noobs like me.